# Hyperledger Composer - Install and join .bna on a second peer of a different organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm using Hyperledger Composer v0.19.4.

I have a blockchain network that has two different organization (PartOwner and Warehouse), each with one peer. I have installed and started the .bna on the peer of the first organization, using the following commands:

> composer network install -c PartOwner-PeerAdmin@channel2 -a carauction-network.bna
>
> composer network start -c PartOwner-PeerAdmin@channel2 -n carauction-network -V 1.0.0 -A PartOwnerAdmin -C ./certs/PartOwner-BnaAdmin/admin-pub.pem

At this point i want the peer of the second organization to join the network.
Which steps must be completed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the official tutorial for multi organization network https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org. Also you need to provide certificates of network administrators for both orgs.Currently you are giving certificate of only PartOwner. Other steps are detailed in the link.